# Validity in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

I am really confused with validity in First Order Logic. Which is the difference between:

$(\exists x)Fx$ being valid and $(\forall x)Fx$ being valid? Does the second one imply the first one?

Any examples on the theory of the reals? For instance, the example $(\forall x)[(\exists y)(x>y)]$. It is true. But what about its satisfiability and validity?

Comment: Are the code lines meant to denote $(\exists x)Fx$, $(\forall x)Fx$, and $(\forall x)[(\exists y)(x > y)]$?

Comment: Completely. Sorry for the syntax.

Comment: *Valid* means: true in every interpretation. $\forall x (x=x)$ is valid, while $\forall x Fx$ is not.

Comment: And yes; in the standard semantics of FOL with non-empty domains, $\forall x Fx$ implies $\exists x Fx$.

Comment: If the formula above is true in the domain of *reals*, then it is satisfiable. But it is not valid, i.e. true in every interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! You mean that, for instance, I could invent a "theory of the integers from 0 to 10" and in that case (∀)[(∃)(>)] would not be true, so it is not valid? If that is so, validity in FOL seems like a really strong property, and I can only think about tautologies. Any example more so that I can develop more intuition?